# How to wait for Angular2 to finish rendering

Tags: dart, angular

In case it matters, here's the reason I want to do this:
My application will have many elements in various places on the same page that each trigger individually tiny http requests for small (less than a kilobyte, sometimes only tens of bytes) pieces of data. To avoid excessive per-request overhead, I want to combine them all into one larger request. I've got the code for combining and handling the combined request and response done, but I'm not sure how to tell when the requests have stopped coming and it's time to send it.

The idea I'm using right now is to use `new Future.value().whenComplete()` (I'm coding in Dart) to simply wait for the event loop to run, but I don't know whether Angular2's rendering spans multiple iterations of the event loop or not. Is this enough to guarantee Angular2 has invoked every property binding on the page before my http request goes out, and if not how can I get such a guarantee?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with rendering. Are you wanting to do something when all the requests have completed successfully? similar to $q.all from angular 1.x?

Comment: @pixelbits That's not it at all. I want there to not be "all the requests" in the first place. 1) Angular queries property bindings. 2) my aggregation code combines things. 3) A single http request goes to the server. I want to be certain step 1 is completely done before step 3 happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better way.

Instead of

```
new Future.value().whenComplete()
```

You can just use

```
new Future(() {
  // delayed code here
});
```

or to delay a bit more

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), () {
  // delayed code here
});
```